# Change value of some column in xts based on other columns values with lookback

Tags: r, finance, xts

I have the following xts object (representing long/short entries (column 1 and 2) and exit (columns 3 and 4) triggers  with "aggregate" signal column which should be 1 (system is long), -1 (system is short) or 0 (system is flat). I can not make this work for "aggregate" signal column5...

The data:

```
         LongEntrySignal ShortEntrySignal LongExitSignal ShortExitSignal Signal
18.02.93               0                0              1               0      0
19.02.93               0                0              0               1      0
22.02.93               1                0              0               0      1
23.02.93               0                0              0               0      0
24.02.93               0                0              0               0      0
25.02.93               0                0              0               0      0
26.02.93               0                0              1               0      0
01.03.93               0                0              1               0      0
04.03.93               0                1              0               0     -1
05.03.93               0                0              0               0      0
11.03.93               0                0              0               1      0
12.03.93               0                0              1               0      0
```

I would like to transform the data in this form:

```
         LongEntrySignal ShortEntrySignal LongExitSignal ShortExitSignal Signal
18.02.93               0                0              1               0      0
19.02.93               0                0              0               1      0
22.02.93               1                0              0               0      1
23.02.93               0                0              0               0      1
24.02.93               0                0              0               0      1
25.02.93               0                0              0               0      1
26.02.93               0                0              1               0      1
01.03.93               0                0              1               0      0
04.03.93               0                1              0               0     -1
05.03.93               0                0              0               0     -1
11.03.93               0                0              0               1     -1
12.03.93               0                0              1               0      0
```

I tried uprogramming a function like below (but id does not work; the commented out part also does not work and is terribly slow - I am aware of using loops in R is slow but that was the only idea that I had):

```
padMinusPlusOnes<-function(signals, longEntryColumn=1, shortEntryColumn=2, signalsColumn=5) {   
    ret<-signals
#get all indexes between long entry equals 1 to long exit equals 1 and set signalsColumn for these rows to 1
    ret[(lag(ret)[, longEntryColumn] == 1) & (ret[, signalsColumn] == 0), signalsColumn]<-1
#get all indexes between short entry equals 1 to short exit equals 1 and set signalsColumn for these rows to -1
    ret[(lag(ret)[, shortEntryColumn] == -1) & (ret[, signalsColumn] == 0), signalsColumn]<--1

    return(ret)

#   ret<-signals
#   for (i in 2:NROW(ret)) {
#       if ((ret[i - 1, longEntryColumn] == 1) & (ret[, signalsColumn] == 0)) {
#           ret[i, signalsColumn]<-1
#       }
#       if ((ret[i - 1, shortEntryColumn] == -1) & (ret[, signalsColumn] == 0)) {
#           ret[i, signalsColumn]<--1
#       }
#   }
#   
#   return(ret)
}
```

Thanks for your kind help in how to transform the data.

Kind regards, Samo.

Edit note: After receving two very helpful and insightful answers from Prasad Chalasani and J. Winchester I realized I left out important information from how my data is structured. So I changed the data above to better reflect my data and copied original (based on which two answers were based) below:

The data:

```
         LongEntrySignal ShortEntrySignal LongExitSignal ShortExitSignal Signal
18.02.93               0                0              0               0      0
19.02.93               0                0              0               0      0
22.02.93               1                0              0               0      1
23.02.93               0                0              0               0      0
24.02.93               0                0              0               0      0
25.02.93               0                0              0               0      0
26.02.93               0                0              1               0      0
01.03.93               0                0              0               0      0
04.03.93               0                1              0               0     -1
05.03.93               0                0              0               0      0
11.03.93               0                0              0               1      0
12.03.93               0                0              0               0      0
```

I would like to transform the data in this form:

```
         LongEntrySignal ShortEntrySignal LongExitSignal ShortExitSignal Signal
18.02.93               0                0              0               0      0
19.02.93               0                0              0               0      0
22.02.93               1                0              0               0      1
23.02.93               0                0              0               0      1
24.02.93               0                0              0               0      1
25.02.93               0                0              0               0      1
26.02.93               0                0              1               0      1
01.03.93               0                0              0               0      0
04.03.93               0                1              0               0     -1
05.03.93               0                0              0               0     -1
11.03.93               0                0              0               1     -1
12.03.93               0                0              0               0      0
```

Comment: Samo, your comment below says there may be exit signals even when there has not been an entry signal. Is it also possible there are consecutive entry signals with no exit?

Comment: Yes, true, in fact they are. It happens that there are consecutive entry signals (on long and short side of trades) and consecutive exit signals (on both, long and short sides of trades). So, the problem as I saw from the beginning is this: how to find rows from first entry to first exit (separate for long and short side) and make sure the last colmn (Signal) is updated correctly.

Comment: is your question answered correctly? If so, you can accept the best answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: @J. Winchester, both solutions, yours and Parsads are working correctley. I will use Parsads since it is more performant. Thank you very very much for your help. I have some catching up on learning to do in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use loops, nor do you need to "lookback". You can use the vectorized function `cumsum` to get what you want. Assuming your long entry/exit and short entry/exit periods are non-overlapping, you can do this: First make up dummy signals:

```
n <- 15
zeros <- rep(0,n)
LongEnt <- replace(zeros, c(1, 12), 1)
LongEx <- replace(zeros, c(4, 14), 1)
ShortEnt <- replace(zeros, 6, 1)
ShortEx <- replace(zeros, 10, 1)
```

Now do some `cumsum` magic to get the right "aggregate" signal column:

```
SigLong <- cumsum(LongEnt) - cumsum(LongEx) + LongEx
SigShort <- -cumsum(ShortEnt) + cumsum(ShortEx) - ShortEx
> cbind(LongEnt, LongEx, ShortEnt, ShortEx, Signal = SigLong + SigShort)
      LongEnt LongEx ShortEnt ShortEx Signal
 [1,]       1      0        0       0      1
 [2,]       0      0        0       0      1
 [3,]       0      0        0       0      1
 [4,]       0      1        0       0      1
 [5,]       0      0        0       0      0
 [6,]       0      0        1       0     -1
 [7,]       0      0        0       0     -1
 [8,]       0      0        0       0     -1
 [9,]       0      0        0       0     -1
[10,]       0      0        0       1     -1
[11,]       0      0        0       0      0
[12,]       1      0        0       0      1
[13,]       0      0        0       0      1
[14,]       0      1        0       0      1
[15,]       0      0        0       0      0
```

**Update**. According to the OP's modified question, we need to handle the case of arbitrary sequence of entry/exit signals, and find the periods between the *first* entry and the corresponding *first* exit. Here's a way to do this with very simple arihtmetic operations (i.e. no expensive lookbacks or if/else checking). We just need a small modification of the `cumsum` function that I will call `cumplus` -- this is like `cumsum`, except that after taking each sum, it replaces it with 1 or 0 depending on whether it's positive or not:

```
cumplus <- function(y) Reduce(function(a,b) a + b > 0, y, 0, accum=TRUE)[-1]
```

(Incidentally, `Reduce` is a nice way to compactly define a cumulative function without explicitly writing out the `for` loop -- see `?Reduce` for details).

Now take an example of Entry/exit signals:

```
LongEnt <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0)
LongEx <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1)

x <- LongEnt - LongEx  
z <- cumplus(x)
```

This is almost what we want... we just need to insert the 1s at the end of each ones-block.

```
z <- z - c(0,pmin(0,diff(z)))

> cbind(LongEnt, LongEx, signal = z)
      LongEnt LongEx signal
 [1,]       1      0      1
 [2,]       0      0      1
 [3,]       0      0      1
 [4,]       1      0      1
 [5,]       0      0      1
 [6,]       0      0      1
 [7,]       1      0      1
 [8,]       0      0      1
 [9,]       0      1      1
[10,]       0      0      0
[11,]       0      0      0
[12,]       0      1      0
[13,]       1      0      1
[14,]       0      0      1
[15,]       0      0      1
[16,]       1      0      1
[17,]       0      0      1
[18,]       0      0      1
[19,]       0      1      1
[20,]       0      0      0
[21,]       0      1      0
[22,]       1      0      1
[23,]       0      0      1
[24,]       0      1      1
```

Dealing with the short entry/exits would of course be similar.

Comment: :) Thank you very very much. Great. I could not imagine to do this in a way you presented. I would figure this out by myself in a year or two... :) I have some leraning to do...

Comment: Huh, I left out an important piece of information. I can have exit signals generated without having an entry signal. So, there are many occasions when exit signal is fired and there is no open position (no prior long or short position or was closed beforehand)... So, this very elegant solution unfortunately does not work for my particular case. Any ideas maybe on how to make it work?

Comment: Prasad, thank you very very much. It works perfectly and it is performant and elegant. Thanks for helping me learn R.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a couple logical assumptions, namely: the system starts in neutral state (ie zero); if the system leaves "zero state" by an "entry" signal of either type (long/short), the next signal must be an "exit" signal of the same type. If I read your data into a matrix named `sigmat` I can do the following.

```
streamLong <- with(sigmat, LongEntrySignal == 1 | LongExitSignal == 1)
switches <- which(streamLong)
mat <- cbind(c(1, switches), c(switches, length(streamLong) + 1), 0:1)
stateLong <- do.call("c", apply(mat, 1, function(ro)rep(ro[3], ro[2] - ro[1])))

streamShort <- with(sigmat, ShortEntrySignal == 1 | ShortExitSignal == 1)
switches <- which(streamShort)
mat <- cbind(c(1, switches), c(switches, length(streamShort) + 1), 0:1)
stateShort <- do.call("c", apply(mat, 1, function(ro)rep(ro[3], ro[2] - ro[1])))

# EDIT: The entry signal stays "on" until end of the exit day 
# so add one to the on sequences, and subtract one from the off sequences
sigRLE <- rle(stateLong - stateShort)
sigRLE$lengths[-1] <- sigRLE$lengths[-1] + 1:0 + 0:-1
sigmat$signal <- rep(sigRLE$values, sigRLE$lengths)
```

Here is the output.

```
R> sigmat
       date LongEntrySignal ShortEntrySignal LongExitSignal ShortExitSignal Signal signal
1  18.02.93               0                0              0               0      0      0
2  19.02.93               0                0              0               0      0      0
3  22.02.93               1                0              0               0      1      1
4  23.02.93               0                0              0               0      0      1
5  24.02.93               0                0              0               0      0      1
6  25.02.93               0                0              0               0      0      1
7  26.02.93               0                0              1               0      0      1
8  01.03.93               0                0              0               0      0      0
9  04.03.93               0                1              0               0     -1     -1
10 05.03.93               0                0              0               0      0     -1
11 11.03.93               0                0              0               1      0     -1
12 12.03.93               0                0              0               0      0      0
```

Comment: J. Winchester, thanks very much for your help. Will test it and see how it works.

Comment: @Samo, I will leave this answer up in case I am inspired with something clever. For now, I posted a second answer with a for loop solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a "magical" (ie vectorized) way to do this, but for now, here's a workable loop solution.

```
# your example data
sigmat <- structure(list(
  date = structure(c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
  .Label = c("01.03.93", "04.03.93", "05.03.93", "11.03.93", "12.03.93", 
    "18.02.93", "19.02.93", "22.02.93", "23.02.93", "24.02.93", 
    "25.02.93", "26.02.93"), class = "factor"), 
  LongEntrySignal = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
  ShortEntrySignal = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
  LongExitSignal = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
  ShortExitSignal = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
  Signal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
  .Names = c("date", "LongEntrySignal", "ShortEntrySignal", 
    "LongExitSignal", "ShortExitSignal", "Signal"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

# if there is an entry/exit signal, turn on/off
# otherwise keep the same state as the day before
sigShort <- sigmat$ShortEntrySignal - sigmat$ShortExitSignal
sigLong  <- sigmat$LongEntrySignal -  sigmat$LongExitSignal
for(i in 2:nrow(sigmat)) {
  if(sigShort[i] == 0) sigShort[i] <- sigShort[i-1]
  if(sigLong[i]  == 0) sigLong[i]  <- sigLong[i-1]
}

# The entry signal stays "on" until end of the exit day 
# so extend the on sequences by one day, and shorten the off sequences
sigRLE <- rle((sigLong > 0) * 1 - (sigShort > 0) * 1)
sigRLE$lengths[-1] <- sigRLE$lengths[-1] + 1:0 + 0:-1
sigmat$Signal <- rep(sigRLE$values, sigRLE$lengths)
```