# Aggregating a position value based on entry/exit values xts

Tags: r, xts, finance

Im trying to use entry/exit signals to generate a position/signal data column for analysis.  I would like the the entry signals to be cumulative and the exit value to signal for the exit of all current entry positions.  In addition I would like to be able to handle being given an exit signal without any current entry positions (of course, this should result in nothing).  I cannot seem to reasonably incorporate this last function while preserving the cumulative properties.

I thought I could get there with this solution.  I just couldnt get the last part to work for me.

[Change value of some column in xts based on other columns values with lookback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135087)

Borrowing some arbitrary Enter/Exit data from the referenced question:

```
> Entry <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
> Exit <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
```

The desired solution would look like this:

```
> DesiredOutcome
      Entry Exit Signal
 [1,]     1    0      1
 [2,]     0    0      1
 [3,]     0    0      1
 [4,]     1    0      2
 [5,]     0    0      2
 [6,]     0    0      2
 [7,]     1    0      3
 [8,]     0    0      3
 [9,]     0    1      3
[10,]     0    0      0
[11,]     0    0      0
[12,]     0    1      0
[13,]     1    0      1
[14,]     0    0      1
[15,]     0    0      1
[16,]     1    0      2
[17,]     0    0      2
[18,]     0    0      2
[19,]     0    1      2
[20,]     0    0      0
[21,]     0    1      0
[22,]     1    0      1
[23,]     0    0      1
[24,]     0    1      1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE.  As requested, here are some attempts at addressing the issue that were not very productive.

Instead of using Entry/Exit/Signal columns one column with nested ifelse statements were attempted to interrogate an indicator (s$Z203 in this case).  Values less than -2 were entry, greater than 2 were exit.

> s$position <- ifelse(s$Z203>=2,0,
>       ifelse(s$Z203<=-2,s$position+1,s$position+lag(s$position)))

Using the multi-column approach i thought I could use simple arithmetic (as in the posted example) and avoid having to query previous lines of the xts object as it iterated through the data.  Having several course columns to accomplish the procedure got me close, but still doesnt address the 1 exit trigger applying to all aggregated entry signals and ignoring an exit signal without any entry positions.

Comment: As currently written, this has nothing to do with xts. Also, StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. You'll get a much better response if you actually show what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: xts was included so any responses would be xts-compatible methods.  As with all things there are innumerable ways to fail and several ways to succeed.  Ill consolidate my failures if it would be useful, but Im afraid it would just be noise.  Ill update with examples.

Comment: Can you explain how the third column is calculated in words?  Why is there a 3 on row 9?  Why is there a 1 on row 13 even though there was an exit on row 12?

Comment: The exit would be generated at the close of the day and so the signal wouldnt update till the following transaction day, so [9,] in this case would trigger the sale of 3 entries on day [10,].  The row 13/12 problem is the one Im stuck on.  [12,] is an exit sell signal but theres nothing to sell.  So the signal column should remain 0.  [13,] triggers a buy (entry) so now theres an equity position sensitive to an exit trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calculating the `cumsum` of `Entry` by group, where group is the `cumsum` of the lagged `Exit` column.  There are lots of ways to "split, apply, combine."  One of them is `ave`:

```
> cbind(Entry, Exit, Signal=ave(Entry, cumsum(c(0, head(Exit, -1))), FUN=cumsum))
      Entry Exit Signal
 [1,]     1    0      1
 [2,]     0    0      1
 [3,]     0    0      1
 [4,]     1    0      2
 [5,]     0    0      2
 [6,]     0    0      2
 [7,]     1    0      3
 [8,]     0    0      3
 [9,]     0    1      3
[10,]     0    0      0
[11,]     0    0      0
[12,]     0    1      0
[13,]     1    0      1
[14,]     0    0      1
[15,]     0    0      1
[16,]     1    0      2
[17,]     0    0      2
[18,]     0    0      2
[19,]     0    1      2
[20,]     0    0      0
[21,]     0    1      0
[22,]     1    0      1
[23,]     0    0      1
[24,]     0    1      1
```

---

If you started with an xts you can do it like this

```
x <- .xts(cbind(Entry, Exit), seq_along(Entry))
x$Signal <- with(xx, ave(Entry, cumsum(c(0, lag(Exit, na.pad=FALSE))), FUN=cumsum))
```

Comment: Ahhh this is outstanding.  I very much appreciate your help.  I wasnt aware of this.  Thanks again!